# How to render the templatetag Context from views.py using Ajax in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

In my template:

```
<div class="widget-content">
    {% render_widget settings %}
</div>
```

`render_widget` is a templatetag which takes `settings` a parameter.

Here we have the code of method defined in templatetag:

```
def render_widget(settings):
   # some processing and then save into context
   t = get_template(#)      
  return t.render(Context(context))
```

The above code works fine!. context is successfully rendering to a given template.

Now i created new method `load_ajax` in `views.py`. Following thing should be happen in this method:

This `load_ajax` method should take the `context` and `t` variable from `render_widget` and render the `context` at `t` template using `'Ajax'`.

I am newbie in Django and Ajax . What should i do ?

### Updated!

load_ajax method:

```
def load_ajax(request):
from myapp.templatetags.file_want_import import render_widget
if request.ajax:
    # some code and render to the template with below lines
return direct_to_template(request, t,
                          extra_context=context)
```

The above `Context` and `t` should come from `render_widget` method.

Comment: Show us load_ajax. It makes little sense. You seem to be mixing up what happens in the view as distinct from what happens when you render a template (thus invoking the templatetag).

Comment: A template tag should not need a view do create output. A template tag generates HTML which is then put into the template. A website can then request a template using ajax and that template can contain a template tag. But these are two separate tasks.

Comment: @SimeonVisser I totally agreed with you that template tag don't need a view to create otuput. Let me clear about my template. My template loading the template tag (as i have mentioned in my question). Now it is giving me output without an Ajax. Now i want to do with the Ajax.

To do this i thought a solution i.e. use this setting parameter in views (That is the main issue. How can i use this parameter in views) i can render the data to template using ***Ajax***.

Comment: @JohnMee Done! but it has nothing. I want to import the data but it is not working (see the updated code!)

Comment: @SimeonVisser see the updated section. It will help you more about it

Answer (score 0):

You've thrown yourself into a logic loop based on misunderstanding how template tags work:

- you're calling the view for a response
- then your view is expecting the templatetag to give it a context
- but templatetags are expected to receive contexts, not provide them

Start over and don't use a templatetag:

- call the view for a response
- put your context together with all the data you need to render the template (it's just a dictionary after all)
- render and return the template

It's easier to collect all your data together in the view then render the template.  It's not clear why you need the template tags.  If you want to render some settings just pass them into the template as part of the context. eg:

view.py:

```
ctx = { "setting_var": settings.some_var }
return render_to_response(... context=ctx)
```

template:

```
<div>
    {{ setting_var }}
</div>
```